# SQLServerAgent could not be started This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled. edition does not support SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent

I've tried to re-install it but nothing works I can't start it even though I've enabled the sa login in windows authentication

Comment: This error message is pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: If you're using Sql Server Express Edition it [doesn't support SQL Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express#Capabilities)

Comment: Okay thank you I'm actually using the express edition, didn't know that. Thank youu very much